# Access remote EJB in jboss 7.1 from jboss 5.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss5.x

I'm migrating an app from jboss 5.1 to jboss 7.1.
Basically i'm creating a new core in a new EAR in Jboss 7.1. I need to access EJB's inside jboss 7.1 from deployed app in Jboss 5.1.

I added jboss-client.jar in my EAR jboss 5.1 to remote connect EJB in jboss 7.1 but my jboss 5.1 doesn't start when that jar is attached.
I'm following [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI) tutorial.

Is that possible? From Jboss 5.1 to Jboss 7.1 access remote EJB?

Comment: This solution is so bad that no one knows how to solve?

Comment: Many people dislike EJB forgo it.